# an error occurred when i implement the alert dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

the code was running until i implement the alertdialog activity. The activity breaks when it opens the code.

The class and the oncreate function:

```
    public class NewTask extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
    AlertDialog error = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
                Button Done, Date;
                Task newtask=new Task();
                TextView dateview,prob;
                EditText name,desc;
                RadioGroup prio;
                int year,month,day;
                static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_task);
            initialize();
            Setdate();
            done();
                }
```

the usage of the dialog

```
               prio.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    Done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            newtask.name=name.getText().toString();
            newtask.discrb=desc.getText().toString();
            if(newtask.name.length()==0||newtask.day==0||newtask.periocheck==0||newtask.discrb.length()==0)
            {
                error.setTitle("ERROR");
                error.setMessage("Please fill all the fields!!!");  
                error.setButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
                error.show();
            }
            else if(newtask.year<c.get(Calendar.YEAR)||(newtask.year==c.get(Calendar.YEAR)&&(newtask.month)<c.get(Calendar.MONTH))||(newtask.year==c.get(Calendar.YEAR)&&(newtask.month)==c.get(Calendar.MONTH)&&newtask.day<c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)))
            {
                error.setTitle("ERROR");
                error.setMessage("Choose an existing day!!!");  
                error.setButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
                error.show();
            }
```

so please help me to find out the error

Comment: Please add the resulting error messages from LogCat to the post.

Comment: initialize the alertdialog inside each if block not globally

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
if(newtask.name.length()==0||newtask.day==0||newtask.periocheck==0||newtask.discrb.length()==0)
            {
               DialogFragment error = new ErrorMessage();
               error.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Error");

            }
```

Create `ErrorMessage` class like this:

```
public class ErrorMessage extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("Choose an existing day!!!");
               ...//Add title buttons here
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Good luck!